# I cannot figure out RouteConfig.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am very new to MVC and trying to build my first website. I couldnt set my RouteConfig file properly. I have 2 rules that apply to different ActionResults. But, only one of them works properly. if GetProducts is above the  GetProductByCode, then GetProducts works. If GetProductByCode is above the GetProducts, then GetProductByCode works. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetProducts",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{PageNo}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetProducts", PageNo = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetProductByCode",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{ProductCode}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetProductByCode", ProductCode = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

My Solution is like below

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetProducts",
            url: "{controller}/GetProducts/{PageNo}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetProducts", PageNo = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetProductByCode",
            url: "{controller}/GetProductByCode/{ProductCode}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetProductByCode", ProductCode = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the default route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Then think of the portion after `url:` as a format or pattern:

- {controller}
- {action}
- {id}

Your 3 URLs `Home/GetProducts`, `Home/GetProductsByCode` and `Home/Index` all match this pattern.

With the {action} portion being `GetProducts`, `GetProductsByCode` and `Index` respectively.

You would need to leverage routing if you wanted to map the parameter to a variables called `PageNo` or `ProductCode` in the Action, but in general you don't need routes for each possible combination. If your parameters in these actions are id then it will just work without you needing to create routes for each.

E.g.

```
public ActionResult GetProducts(int id) 
{
 // stuff
}

public ActionResult GetProductsByCode(string id)
{
 // stuff
}
```

To have the parameter names, specify the controller and action explicitly:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
        name: "GetProducts",
        url: "Home/GetProducts/{PageNo}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetProducts", PageNo = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "GetProductByCode",
        url: "Home/GetProductsByCode/{ProductCode}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetProductByCode", ProductCode = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

And

```
public ActionResult GetProducts(int PageNo) 
{
 // stuff
}

public ActionResult GetProductsByCode(string ProductCode)
{
 // stuff
}
```

But in general, only define custom routes that differ from the normal `{controller}/{action}/{id}` pattern.

---

The default section of `MapRoute` means that if it can't find a `controller` and `action` that exists in your code base use these instead. It's a fallback, not the functionality driver.

Comment: thanks for your help, now I understood everything about it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

All 3 routes are identical in that they contain 3 segments (the controller name, action name and an optional parameter) and which ever of the 3 are placed first will always be hit.

If you want `GetProducts` to be hit the you could modify the definition to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetProducts",
    url: "Home/GetProducts/{PageNo}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetProducts", PageNo = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

although there seems no real point. If you just changed the name of the parameter in the `GetProducts()` and `GetProductByCode()` to `id` then the only route definition you require is the Default

Comment: I didnt understand, would you please write the correct way of GetProducts and GetProductByCode, please?

Comment: The method in your controller should be `public ActionResult GetProducts(int id)` not `GetProducts(int PageNo)` and then you only need one route (the "Default").

Answer (score 1):

There is not way for asp.net to understand if the last parameter is /{ProductCode}", or {ProductCode}", since the action is the same - so your URL looks the same,
Therefor only the first match is taken, a solution would be using a full query string since the /{id} is just a shorthand for id=5 in the query string

Comment: but actions are different

Comment: The action automativly substituted and mapped to the controller, which means that the action name /home/GetProducts for example will be mapped to the correct action. but the template is always the same "{controller}/{action}/{some_kind_of_int}" so basicly it is all the same like default. you could remove both rules. and they will map

Adding a rule would be good if you needed to pass 2 parameters or make another kind of path.